# Jenkins change Build History timestamps

Tags: jenkins, build, timestamp, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Multibranch Pipeline in Jenkins. 
My goal is to change the Timestamps of the Builds in the History.
I was able to change the DisplayName (#13 to 'test') as shown in the picture below, but not the timestamp. Is this possible, and if so, how?

[image]

Comment: `change the Timestamps of the Builds in the History` what do you mean by History ? Are you talking about git submission history?

Comment: @DupinderSingh I'm talking about the Build History. When a pipeline is being started, triggered by webhook or manually, the run will appear in the build history of the pipeline. I want to change the timestamp to a date of my choice. Similar to the Git option (git commit --date), which makes it possible to set any data, regardless of the real date. Is this also possible for Jenkins builds?

Comment: https://plugins.jenkins.io/timestamper/, please have a look into this if it could help

Comment: Hey @JaCo I posted one answer, which will full fill your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

After googling for some time I found one wonderful plugin.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy-postbuild/

**Groovy Post Build.**

This plugin can help you to add custom text, plugin-predefined Icons In `Build History` side pane after build `Timestamp`. Like 
[image]

And this plugin has some other icons also and we can give on hover to those icons.

It's really fun to implement cool stuff there. This plugin has very good documentation and well-defined Examples.

Please have a look, This will resolve your problem.

PS: you need to write some groovy script

[update]

**Install plugin:**

Jenkins > configure > manage plugin > Avaialble > search for Groovy PostBuild > Install and restart Jenkins

**How to use:**

Start Configure your project. If the project is FreeStyle then go to post build tab in the configuration page. Like this:

---

[image]

---

A textArea will open now add your Script as described in Examples.

---

[image]

---

Now Apply and save. Run the build and tadaaaa.. your message is in build history pane.

---

[image]

---

I think this could help you to setup and run script